# keyup executing multiple times

Tags: jquery, html

The internal keyup function is executing multiple times , when I only want it to execute once for every keystroke. The internal keyup should only work when the length is above 3 and once for every keystroke.
here is the code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Adder function using JQuery</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <input  type = 'text' class="parent"/>
    </main>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function()
    {
        var parent = 0, child = 0;
       'use strict';
       $('.parent').keyup(function()
    {
        console.log("parent part is executed\t" + ++parent + " times");
        if($('.parent').val().length >3)
        $('.parent').keyup(function()
    {
        console.log("now inside another keyup function\t" + ++child + " times");
    })
    }) 
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

can anyone tell me why is it happening and is there any alternative for this?

Comment: Instead of using the event in `$(document).ready(function())`, use the `keyup`, directly.

Comment: and you have nested the `keyup` event, please make them separate

Comment: the `$(document).ready(function())` function was a need in my original code, where the script is at `<head>` part and I need them to be nested as the internal `keyup` should execute only after the outer `keyup` is executed.

Comment: and separating them , the inner `keyup` does not work

Comment: but why do you need an inner `keyup`, using two nested `keyup`s is not logical, how can one keyup execute in another, you just need a status or a flag to do the inner functioning. Or you can avoid that too

Comment: and always use the external scripts, because it doesnt block your page from loading if there is any error.

Comment: never mind ,the code works thanks for the response..

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('.parent').val().length >3)
        $('.parent').keyup(function()
    {
        console.log("now inside another keyup function\t" + ++child + " times");
    })
```

remove if loop condition with following code so your if loop works when parents value will greater than 3

```
if(parent >3)
        $('.parent').keyup(function()
    {
        console.log("now inside another keyup function\t" + ++child + " times");
    })
```

Comment: child function is still not executing, anyway I found another method to my code.
Thanks for the response.